# Get image after it is uploaded using angular and node

Tags: node.js, angular, object, file-upload, blob

I have a simple reactive form in angular 6 that it also has a file input to upload images.

The scenario is to submit the form, save the image and the text fields of the form and then update a photo gallery with the new image. For a photo gallery, I use the [ng carousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api).

This is the code in the front-end

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm($event.target)" >
  <input type="file" (change)='imageChange($event)' formControlName="imageInput" name = 'imageInput'> 
  <input type="text" formControlName="imageName" name='imageName'>
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>  
</form>
```

save it like

```
  submitForm(form){
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/upload',formData,{reportProgress:true,observe:'events'}).subscribe(
      event=>{
        if(event.type === HttpEventType.Response){     
          eb = event.body;              
            this.addpic(eb.data);            
        }        
    }); 
}
```

`eb.data` contains data that came from the server, after successfully saving the form data, the id of the new image and its file name.

In `addpic` I try to add a new image in the carousel. Add all the new data to an array, so I can use the array later, to `ngFor` it and dynamically create the ng Carousel

```
  addpic(data){  
    this.images.push({
      'id': data.id,
      'name': data.name
     });
  }
```

use it like so

```
<ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="images" > 
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let im of images; let i = index"  id="{{im.id}}">
    <img src='../assets/images{{im.newName}}' >
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

So this works fine, but the image is never rendered. I get no errors, I see all the data saved in my database, the image is transferred in the folder as it should, but no new image in the carousel, just a 404 error in the console. The  `images` array is updated, but no image in the carousel. The URL is ok, all the other images with the same URL are rendered in the carousel. It's like the app had no time to see the whole update, so it cannot show the image.

I tried to grab the image file object from the form, save it in angular in a `selectedFile: File;` and use this in the carousel, but this has no `path` or anything similar. Grab it when it is set in the form

```
  imageChange(e){            
    this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
  }
```

and use it in `addpic`

```
  addpic(data){  
    this.images.push({
      'id': data.id,
      'name': this.selectedFile.path
     });
  }
```

I also tried to use the `formData` before the form submission, t get the image,  but the result is the same, an object with no path.

I also tried to "read" the file using HTML5 `FileReader`, but this is an image and in the carousel, I need to provide a URL for the `src`, not just the image file.

I also used formidable in the node to parse the form and take the path of the image, return it back in the front-end along with the id and the file name and use that as an `src`. But this won't be used by the browser for security reasons I guess, because it is a URL in the temp files.

I also tried to get all the images from the server with a query, but the new image is still not available, giving a 404 error, even though the image is in the folder and the database is updated.

like this

```
  addpic(data){
    this.getImages(this.currentId); //get all images again   
     this.images.push({
      'id': this.images.id,
      'name': this.images.path
     }); 
  }
```

I have to refresh the page for the image to show. I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas? Is it a security issue that I cannot get the image right away, even though it is saved and I have to refresh? I would like to avoid performing an extra `get`, if it is possible, to keep client-server communication minimum.

I use angular6 and node 8.11. in windows 10, all locally in my laptop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Might be issue related to updated variable refers to same reference. inside addPic(). add this line of code as last line.

```
this.images = this.images.slice();
```

Comment: Ah, so you use a copy of the array, hoping that will get the image by that time. Clever, but unfortunately, it did not fix my problem. Any other ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the ng-bootstrap version you are using? current version 3.2.2 has some issue on carousel. You can try 2.2.2

Comment: I updated to 2.2.2 `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",` but still the same problem...

Comment: When I update to ng bootstrap 2.2.2, the new last image will not show, even after refresh. So I went back to the ng bootstrap 2.2.0. The problem now is that with every click previous or next image in the carousel I get `The specified value "ll" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?` and `The specified value "nu" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?`

Comment: Those are warnings and they appear with every previous or next click, in all carousel images old or new. I have no clue what they are, but I think you should know,maybe they will help us find a solution. I will also prepare a stackblitz and send you the link

Comment: Here is a big part of the app and the logic. Its a lot of code, so ask me anything. Thanks [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iljtgc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi there again. I asked again. I hope this better explains my problem and the stackblitz is better. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582417/angular-does-not-find-an-uploaded-image) Thank you