# angular does not find an uploaded image

Tags: angular, image, url, file-upload, angular6

The scenario is simple. Use a form to upload an image and if it is successfully uploaded, refresh a photogallery. I use angular6 and [ng-carousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api). All the system is locally set in my windows 10 laptop.

The form gets uploaded, the text data are saved on the database and the image is saved in a file in node 8.11.1. I save the image in the `src/assets/images`. I can see the changes and I get no errors while uploading.

But, after the upload, I try to use the URL of the new image to add it as the last image in the carousel and all I get is a 404 error. The URL is like `http://localhost:4200/assets/images/unsplash.jpg` The URL is valid, the image is there and all the other carousel images use the same URL. But, the new image has a 404 error. I have to recompile the angular app to see the image. Not just refresh the page, recompile the whole app.

I dont know how to fix this. I tried using a File object or the HTML5 FileReader API on the front end and not depend on creating a URL after image upload. But they dont have a URL and the ng-carousel needs a URL like `/assets/images/img.jpg` to work. In order to use some kind of URL, I also tried to get the temporary URL from node and return it back to the front-end, but since it is a `temp` folder URL, browser wont let me use it. I also tried to use [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) but is not supported in all browsers. I also tried to perform a `GET` after the image is saved and get all the images names from the database, to loop them again and feed the carousel template once again. Nothing. Still a 404 error. I have to recompile the app.

What is happening? Is this a angular 6 issue? Security restriction? Please help me fix this, I dont know how to deal with it anymore.

Outline of code.

the form

```
<form *ngIf="pointPartsActive" [formGroup]="imageUpload" (ngSubmit)="imageUploadSubmitted($event.target)" >
  <input type="file"  (change)='imageChange($event)' #imageInput id="imageInput" name = 'imageInput'  accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif" formControlName="imageInput" > 
  <input type="text" formControlName="imageName" name='imageName' placeholder="name" >
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>  
</form>
```

html carousel template, add custom html to also delete an image on the spot.

```
<ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="images" (slide)="onSlide($event)"> 
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let im of images; let i = index"  id="{{im.id}}">
    <img src='../assets/images/{{im.name}}' >
    <div class='carousel-img-details'>
        <button type="button" (click)='deletepic(im.photoId)'>delete</button>   
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

form submit

```
  imageUploadSubmitted(form){  
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    let eb =null;
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/upload',formData,{reportProgress:true,observe:'events'}).subscribe(
      event=>{        
        if(event.type === HttpEventType.Response){     
          eb = event.body;              
          if(eb.success){                  
            this.imageUpload.reset();                                                 
            this.addpic(eb.data);            
          }
        }        
    }); 
  }
```

after successful form submit, update the array that feeds the carousel. Its a simple array of json objects like `[{'id':1,'name':'James'},{'id':2,'name':'Nolan'}]` and feeds the carousel via `ngFor`.

```
  addpic(data){
    let slide = null;    
    this.images.push({
        'photoId':Number(data.id)
        'id': this.images.length,   
        'name': data.name    
    });     
     //get the id of the last slide and go there :          
     setTimeout(() => {
      slide = this.images[this.images.length-1].id;    
      this.carousel.select(slide); 
     });
     this.images = this.images.slice(); //try to "refresh" array itself
  }
```

The code logic in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7wue7m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thanks

Comment: to clarify: Are you uploading the image to the assets folder?
When you run your application localy, are you running it with ng serve, or are you running it from a node server after ng build. There are two assets folders, on in src and one in dist, if you run the application with build the image must be in the dist folder.

Comment: @Engam Yes. The URL is `http://localhost:4200/assets/images/1537906640981-unsplash.jpg`

Comment: @Engam One CMD runs `nodemon` for node 8.11.1 and another one runs `ng serve` for angular6. I save the images in `src/assets/images` . Did I mention I am a newbie? Oh God, this is some silly detail and I just wasted all this time and also everyone's time, right?

Comment: In the stackblitz after select the image, I see this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at FileReader.reader.onload (app.component.ts:52)

Comment: @Kalamarico I lost you. In what function? I see 52 an empty line between checkfiles and readfiles.

Comment: @Engam So, I should change the folder I save the images? How about save them in `public` of node?

Comment: no worries:) I tried to test something similar by dragging a image into my own assets/images folder and then go to the url directly, no luck for the new image, but worked fine with older images. Looks like the angular app have to be recompiled for the image to be accessible. Maybe you can change the code to instead of saving the image in the angular assets folder, you can let the backend serve the images instead (the node/nodemon server)?

Comment: @Engam Yes, I will try to save them in the `public` folder of node and retrieve them from there, using the URL. I I will test tomorrow and let you know

Comment: @Engam Hi again. Looks like I cannot reach a folder outside the angular src folder. I try to reach the `http://localhost:4200/public/images/1.jpg` and the browser automatically goes to `http://localhost:4200` . The `public/images` I try to go to, is in my node js project `C:\project\public\images` in the same level with the views and routes folders.

Comment: @Engam I set the assets in my `angular.json` as `"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/images"
            ],` . Maybe there is another way to set assets?

Comment: @Engam OK, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274691/cannot-get-relative-image-path-in-angular-6) . So I guess the app will always need recompile to show a new image, no matter what you set as an assets folder. I hope that when you build the app, the dist/assets will show a new image right away. Can you elaborate a little more on the "let the backend serve the images instead (the node/nodemon server)" part, because this may be a good alternative? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution for you:

For a live application you probably would want to save your images on a fileserver (for. example AWS S3 on Amazon AWS), and store the link to this file in a database.

For your localhost project you can use [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server#readme) to function as this fileserver or you can use the [express framework](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) with ur node application.

```
npm install http-server -g
http-server C:/link/to/a/folder/you/have/saved/the/images/in
```

Then you must save the link to your file, either in a db (database) or inn a textfile. For this I would recomend that you setup a local [MongoDB database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/). This might take some time for you to get into, but it is good learning experience. You can use https://mongoosejs.com/ to communicate with your node application.

Then when you upload a new image, you send it from your frontend Angular app, to your backend node/express application, save the file in the folder and save the link in the db. With the https-server you will be able to access the image right away (with maybe som delay). And with the links stored in the db you can send the data in the db to your front end with a http get request whenever you refresh your application.

I hope this will help you to reach your goal :)

Comment: I have node+express/angular/postgres . I save the image name in the db and try to recreate the URL in angular, in the carousel, like `<img src='../assets/images/{{im.name}}' >` as you see in the template. I have all that you advice. The ONLY problem right now is that 404/assets folder thing. It makes sense to put everything in the assets, since they will end up there. So, unless assets in dist can automatically give back a valid URL of a new uploaded image, I am fried? Angular just leaves me hanging, with options being amazon and more packages? For a simple image URL??Great work Angular !

Comment: I guess I have to build the app and test how dist responds. Otherwise I will test the  `http-server`. How can I alternatively use express? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses AOT(Ahead of Time) compiling which will read the already existing files that are available when compiling. The uploaded images are to be saved in the server-side code, for example: in a folder `server/uploads`.

When the API to avail the links of the images are called, the response can have the `baseURL/file-name`. For the development server in your case, it would be `localhost:3000/uploads/unsplash.jpg`. Make sure you have made the uploads folder static.

In case if you are using a node JS (Express) in the server-side, here's an example

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

app.get('/gallery',(req, res) => {
    fs.readdir(('./uploads'),(err,files) => {
            let filePath = []
            files.forEach(filename => {
                filePath.push('http://localhost:3000/uploads/' + filename)
            })
            res.json({
                files: filePath
            })
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port:', 3000)
})
```

This will provide you with the paths of the images in the `uploads` folder and can be viewed in the client-side unlike storing it in the assets folder