# Angular gives me image not found after upload

Tags: angular, nestjs, angular-universal

after uploading an image into my assets/folder (directly via a form) I cannot assess the URL of the image until I rebuild the app.... I'm using Angular Universal version 9 with NestJS version ^6.11.6 and to combine both I'm using ng-universal.

I've seen another thread about someome having a similar problem ([angular does not find an uploaded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582417/angular-does-not-find-an-uploaded-image/52593435)) but that thread is pretty old and I'm wondering if there is a solution for his problem now.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The assets folder is meant to be used for items that need to be included in the build without being imported. Have you tried using a different folder, not under assets?

Comment: are you using a reverse proxy (nginx)? How did you configure nestjs to handle static files?

Comment: It's fine, I just used Cloudinary to upload my images and i store the link in the DB.